# Potting a 3D vector field with unknown constants

Tags: plotting, vector

We are trying to show the direction of a certain vector field. we are trying to do this with a 3d vector plot with unknown constants. The function we are trying to plot can be seen in the added picture as well as the error message we get. All help will be appreciated.

[image]

Initial function:

```
V[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_] = q/((4 πϵ)*Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2])
```

Function I would like to plot:

```
MatrixForm[-Grad[V[x,y,z,a,b,c], {x,y,z}]]
```

Comment: Could you include code that other people can copy so it doesn't have to be re-typed?

Comment: The initial function that we used was:
V[x_,y_,z_,a_,b_,c_]= q/((4\[Pi]\[Epsilon])*Sqrt[(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2])
Then we took the negative gradient of that and got
MatrixForm[-Grad[q/((4\[Pi]\[Epsilon])*Sqrt[(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2]),{x,y,z}]]
The outcome of that should be equal to the matrix on the printscreen. thanks for your quick response!

Comment: As the error message says, you can't have variables as bounds for the plotrange of `VectorPlot3D`. If you really have no idea what the values should be, you can wrap the whole `VectorPlot3D[...]` inside [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html). This way, you can play with the bounds easily. Also, can you edit your post to include the code in copyable form formatted as code? (use the buttons in the editor)

Comment: We have added the codes into the initial post. hopefully We did this correctly. The Difficulty we have is that the plot has to be determined for any arbitrary x, y, z, a, b, and c. And we have to show the the field points outward for any arbitrary x, y, z, a, b and c.

Comment: Is `πϵ` supposed to be a single parameter, or is it a typo for `π ϵ`? Whichever, it and `q` will need specific values for any plot.

Comment: Okay thanks. i Managed to do it with given values for those parameters and i think it will be fine. Thanks for all the help.